# how do I iterate through all the entries in /etc/passwd using c?

Tags: c

I would like to iterate through all the record entries in /etc/passwd using just c api calls.

How can I do this?

Note: I've seen lots of examples of how to do this in other languages, but not found any examples in c.

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969582/how-do-i-iterate-through-all-the-entries-in-etc-passwd-using-c

Comment: @dcaswell That links to *this* question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This small program worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct passwd *pw;

    setpwent();
    while ( (pw = getpwent()) != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n", pw->pw_name);
    }
    endpwent();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with answering your own question immediately? Did you mean to post this on your blog?

Comment: Note that this is not thread-safe.  If you need to do this in a multithreaded environment, consider using [`fgetpwent_r(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent_r) instead.

Comment: You know full well there's absolutely nothing wrong with answering your own question, @Kerrek.

Comment: @RobKennedy: If you have a genuine problem and *eventually* figure it out, sure. But posting the question simultaneously with the answer is a bit different.

Comment: I don't see how it's different, @Kerrek. Regardless, [Stack Overflow *specifically supports* posting a question and an answer simultaneously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/33732).